# Getting the world x, y, and z of placed SCNNode - Swift

Tags: swift, arkit, scnnode, arscnview

My objective is to generate a SCNNode in the middle of another SCNNode that contains a SCNPlane.

The SCNPlane is generated in a renderer function like this:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
    let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

    plane.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange

    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

    let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
    let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
    let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    node.name = "plane"

    loadSphere(x:x, y:y, z:z)
```

Im trying to put the sphere right in the middle of a plane as such:

```
func loadSphere (x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, z:CGFloat) {
    let idleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/bounceFixed.dae")!

    // This node will be parent of all the animation models
    let node = SCNNode()

    for child in idleScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        node.addChildNode(child)
    }

    // Set up some properties
    node.name = "Sphere"

    node.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
    node.scale = SCNVector3(0.001, 0.001, 0.001)
    ...
```

But the issue is that whenever I run this, x, y, z, all end up being zero. I've tried things like `sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[3].worldPosition` or `node.worldPosition` but that always ends up generating the sphere right in the view of the camera and not in the middle of the plane.

I've attached a picture here to show you what I mean by the "middle".

[image]

Please let me know how I can remedy this.

EDIT: My goal with this post is to try to get the x, y, z (center) of the plane node without appending the sphere as a child.

Best.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your actual scn scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually seeing your model, or exactly how you are adding your Sphere, I would hazard a guess, that either you aren't adding your model to the correct `SCNNode`, or that the `pivot` of your model is not centered.

If you want to place something centrally on your SCNNode with a plane geometry you can set it's position at `SCNVector3Zero` or ommit it altogether e.g.

```
/// Loads An SCNSphere On A Generated SCNNode
///
/// - Parameter plane: SCNNode
func loadSphereOnPlane(_ plane: SCNNode) {

    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    let sphereNodeGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
    sphereNodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    sphereNode.geometry = sphereNodeGeometry
    plane.addChildNode(sphereNode)

}
```

Whereby you would call this at the end of the `rendererDidAddNode` delegate callback e.g:

```
loadSphereOnPlane(planeNode)
```

If the pivot of your model is not centered you can use something like this to alter it:

```
/// Changes The Pivot To The Center Of The Model
///
/// - Parameter model: SCNNode
func createCentralPivotFor(_ model: SCNNode){

    let (min, max) = model.boundingBox

    let dx = min.x + 0.5 * (max.x - min.x)
    let dy = min.y + 0.5 * (max.y - min.y)
    let dz = min.z + 0.5 * (max.z - min.z)
    model.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(dx, dy, dz)

}
```

An example usage might thus be like so:

```
/// Loads Our Little Scatterbug
func loadScatterBugOnPlane(_ node: SCNNode) {

    let modelPath = "ARModels.scnassets/Scatterbug.scn"

    //1. Get The Reference To Our SCNScene & Get The Model Root Node
    guard let model = SCNScene(named: modelPath),
        let pokemonModel = model.rootNode.childNode(withName: "RootNode", recursively: false) else { return }

    let scatterBug = pokemonModel

    //2. Scale The Scatterbug
    scatterBug.scale = SCNVector3(0.002, 0.002, 0.002)

    //3. Set The Pivot
    createCentralPivotFor(scatterBug)

    //4. Add It To The Plane
    node.addChildNode(scatterBug)

}
```

Which you could also  call at the end of the rendererDidAddNode delegate callback e.g:

Both methods result in something like this:

[image]

**Update:**

Since you have now changed your question, you can try something like this:

```
/// Loads An SCNSphere At The Position Of An ARAnchor
///
/// - Parameter plane: SCNNode
func loadSphereAtAnchorPosition(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {

    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    let sphereNodeGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
    sphereNodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    sphereNode.geometry = sphereNodeGeometry

    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(anchor.transform.columns.3.x,
                                     anchor.transform.columns.3.y,
                                     anchor.transform.columns.3.z)

    augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: just curious, is there any way of doing this would appending it to the child of the plane? saw there's something having to do with ``worldTransform.translation`` but im not sure how to implement it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please mark as correct so the question can be marked as completed.